# Picking objects with mouse ray

Tags: opengl, mouse, raycasting, picking

I simply want to pick a few spheres in my scene using the mouse-ray. I have implemented(copied most of it but with little understanding) a ray-sphere collision code. Also I have implemented the code for converting the mouse window coords to OpenGL coords. And constructed the mouse function. I have a ray class. In other words I have made everything, but sth isn't working...

So, there is the ray-sphere collision code:

```
bool Sphere::CheckRayCollision(Ray mouseRay)
{
     double discriminant, b;

     b = -DotProduct(mouseRay.GetOrigin(), mouseRay.GetDirection());
     discriminant = b * b - DotProduct(mouseRay.GetOrigin(), mouseRay.GetOrigin()) + this->radius * this->radius;

     if(discriminant < 0)
     {
         std::cout<<"disc"<<std::endl;
         return false;
     }
     discriminant = sqrt(discriminant);

     double x1 = b - discriminant;
     double x2 = b + discriminant;

     if(x2 < 0) 
     {
          std::cout<<"x2"<<std::endl;
          return false;
     }
     if(x1 < 0)
     {
           x1 = 0;
           return true;
     }

     return true;
}
```

It is within the sphere class. The convertion between window and OGL coords:

```
Vector3d MouseClass::ConvertMouseToOGLCoordinate(int mouseX, int mouseY, int mouseZ)
{
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble modelMatrix[16];   
    GLdouble projectionMatrix[16];  

    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelMatrix);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projectionMatrix);

    //float winZ;
    float winY = float(viewport[3] - mouseY);
    //glReadPixels(mouseX, (int)winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);

    double x, y, z;
    gluUnProject((double)mouseX, winY, mouseZ, 
        modelMatrix, projectionMatrix, viewport,
        &x, &y, &z);

    return Vector3d(x, y, z);
}
```

And the function which checks whether the left mouse btn is clicked and if it is checks for the collision:

```
void HandleMouse()
{
    if(userMouse.IsLeftButtonDown())
    {
        int cursorX = int(userMouse.GetCurrentPosition().GetX());
        int cursorY = int(userMouse.GetCurrentPosition().GetY());

        Vector3d nearPoint = MouseClass::ConvertMouseToOGLCoordinate(cursorX, cursorY, 0.0f);
        Vector3d farPoint = MouseClass::ConvertMouseToOGLCoordinate(cursorX, cursorY, 1.0f);

        Vector3d direction = farPoint - nearPoint;
        direction.Normalize();

        positionInWorld = farPoint;

        mouseRay = Ray(nearPoint, direction);
        drawCube = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            bool isCollided = sphere[i].CheckRayCollision(mouseRay);
            if(isCollided)
            {
                sphere[i].SetColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            }
            else
            {
                sphere[i].SetColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

The 'drawCube' bool var is just for me to show if the convertion func works well and the 'positionInWorld' var is for the cubes coords. The drawing is well, so I think the convertion function works, but I might've done sth wrong.

If anyone can help me sort out why isn't this code working I would be very gratefull! I have been struggling with this for a week and searched everywhere on the Internet and haven't found a solution yet...

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The picking isn't working here. Pressing the left mouse button doesn't select anything. No matter where I click...

Comment: You forgot to tell what exactly isn't working.

Comment: The picking. The mouse won't select anything, although the left button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was debugging mouse picking in my game, I had it set up to draw a line from my camera to where ever the picking function ended. It lets you know if the ray is going the right direction, and if the ray is ending too soon, or too late.

In your case, I'd have it draw a line between nearPoint and farPoint. Make sure those are the rays you want.

I imagine you'll find that it's not working the way you want it to, and here's why.

```
Vector3d nearPoint = MouseClass::ConvertMouseToOGLCoordinate(cursorX, cursorY, 0.0f);
Vector3d farPoint = MouseClass::ConvertMouseToOGLCoordinate(cursorX, cursorY, 1.0f);
```

That's **not** the way you want to get the nearPoint. The near point has nothing to do with where the mouse cursor is, it's about where your camera is. I created an answer a while back about picking: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/12370/7191

You may want to look at how I get the ray in world coordinates.

Good luck!

Comment: I am currently trying the code from the post. I hope it works. I have one question, though, what Vector4f is about?

Comment: Ok, I found out that the ray is correct. But still no detection for  collision. Maybe the collision code isn't right? Btw, I made the near vector point my camera (nearPoint = Vector3d(0.0f, 0.0f, 99.0f))

Comment: How do you know the ray is correct? You viewed the line for the ray? And the ray does pass through the sphere, but doesn't detect is? So your camera is fixed then? Otherwise setting it to a static point isn't going to work.

Comment: Yes, my camera is fixed. The ray does pass through the sphere and it doesn't detect it.

Comment: Just curious, how can you see that the ray passed through the sphere if your camera is fixed? You would be looking at the ray from directly behind, it would just look like a point. Anyway, if it is passing through the sphere then you've probably narrowed your problem down to the sphere collision code. It looks fairly correct, the only thing I can't tell on is the DotProduct function. Have you double checked that? Put a break point at the top, calculate the variables by hand, then step through your code and ensure you get the same answer.

Comment: Well, it isn't a dot it is a line from the center of openGL window to the cursor position. I also draw a square at the end of the line, so I can see when it is behind the sphere. I worry about that the end of the line is at the farPoint position. I would post a picture if it would clear things out.

Comment: If you can see the line, then it is not going from the camera to the position you clicked in the world. If you were to shoot a beam(pick ray) out of your eye (camera), you could not see the beam from the side. Since you're behind it. You could only see it from the back, where it would look like a point. You should post screen shots.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2079/discussion-between-byte56-and-tsvetan)