# Ray Picking Problems

Tags: lwjgl, picking

I've read so many answers on here about how to do Ray Picking, that I thought I had the idea of it down.  But when I try to implement it in my game, I get garbage.

I'm working with LWJGL.

Here's the code:

```
public static Ray getPick(int mouseX, int mouseY){
    glPushMatrix();

    //Setting up the Mouse Clip
    Vector4f mouseClip = new Vector4f((float)mouseX * 2 / 960f - 1, 1 - (float)mouseY * 2 / 640f ,0 ,1);

    //Loading Matrices
    FloatBuffer modMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    FloatBuffer projMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modMatrix);
    glGetFloat(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projMatrix);

    //Assigning Matrices
    Matrix4f proj = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f model = new Matrix4f();
    model.load(modMatrix);
    proj.load(projMatrix);

    //Multiplying the Projection Matrix by the Model View Matrix
    Matrix4f tempView = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f.mul(proj, model, tempView);
    tempView.invert();

    //Getting the Camera Position in World Space.  The 4th Column of the Model View Matrix.
    model.invert();
    Point cameraPos = new Point(model.m30, model.m31, model.m32);

    //Theoretically getting the vector the Picking Ray goes
    Vector4f rayVector = new Vector4f();
    Matrix4f.transform(tempView, mouseClip, rayVector);
    rayVector.translate((float)-cameraPos.getX(),(float) -cameraPos.getY(),(float) -cameraPos.getZ(), 0f);
    rayVector.normalise();
    glPopMatrix();

    //This Basically Spits out a value that changes as the Camera moves.
    //When the Mouse moves, the values change around 0.001 points from screen edge to edge.
    System.out.format("Vector: %f %f %f%n", rayVector.x, rayVector.y, rayVector.z);

    //return new Ray(cameraPos, rayVector);
    return null;
}
```

I don't really know why this isn't working.  I was hoping some more experienced eyes might be able to help me out.

I can get the camera position like a champ, it's the vector the rays going in that I can't seem to get right.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

knight666,

I translated your code, and here's what I came up with:

```
public static Ray getPick(int mouseX, int mouseY){
    glPushMatrix();

    //Setting up the Mouse Clip
    Vector2f mouseClip = new Vector2f((mouseX / 960f) * 2f - 1f, (mouseY / 640f) * 2f - 1f);

    //Loading Matrices
    FloatBuffer modMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    FloatBuffer projMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modMatrix);
    glGetFloat(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projMatrix);

    //Assigning Matrices
    Matrix4f proj = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f model = new Matrix4f();
    model.load(modMatrix);
    proj.load(projMatrix);

    //Multiplying the Projection Matrix by the Model View Matrix
    Matrix4f tempView = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f.mul(proj, model, tempView);
    tempView.invert();

    //Getting the Camera Position in World Space.  The 4th Column of the Model View Matrix.
    //model.invert();
    Point cameraPos = new Point(-model.m30, -model.m31, -model.m32);

    //Getting Mouse Position in 3D Space
    Vector4f pOne = new Vector4f(mouseClip.x, mouseClip.y, -1f, 1f);
    Vector4f pTwo = new Vector4f(mouseClip.x, mouseClip.y,  1f, 1f);
    Vector4f nearPoint = new Vector4f();
    Vector4f farPoint = new Vector4f();
    Matrix4f.transform(tempView, pOne, nearPoint);
    Matrix4f.transform(tempView, pTwo, farPoint);

    Vector3f pOneNorm = new Vector3f(pOne.x / pOne.w, pOne.y / pOne.w, pOne.z / pOne.w);
    Vector3f pTwoNorm = new Vector3f(pTwo.x / pTwo.w, pTwo.y / pTwo.w, pTwo.z / pTwo.w);

    Vector3f rayVector = new Vector3f();
    Vector3f.sub(pTwoNorm, pOneNorm, rayVector);

    rayVector.normalise();

    glPopMatrix();

    return new Ray(cameraPos, rayVector);
    //return null;
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a ray with the vector of (0,0,-2) that doesn't change when I move the mouse.

As I understood it, Matrix4f.transform(matrix, vector, newVector) is the same as newVector = matrix * vector.  Unfortunately in LWJGL, I can't use the former.  I'm not sure if that's the case of what's going wrong or not.

I appreciate the help!

**Edit #2**

Here's the current method, with Byte56's updates:

```
public static Ray getPick(int mouseX, int mouseY){
    float windowWidth = 960f;
    float windowHeight = 640f;

    float aspectRatio = windowWidth / windowHeight;

    //get the mouse position in screenSpace coords
    double screenSpaceX = ((float) mouseX / (windowWidth / 2) - 1.0f) * aspectRatio;
    double screenSpaceY = (1.0f - (float) mouseY / (windowHeight / 2));

    double viewRatio = Math.tan((float) Math.PI / 4.0f / 2.00f);

    screenSpaceX = screenSpaceX * viewRatio;
    screenSpaceY = screenSpaceY * viewRatio;

    float NearPlane = 1f;
    float FarPlane = 100f;

    //Find the far and near camera spaces
    Vector4f cameraSpaceNear = new Vector4f((float) (screenSpaceX * NearPlane), (float) (screenSpaceY * NearPlane), (float) (-NearPlane), 1);
    Vector4f cameraSpaceFar = new Vector4f((float) (screenSpaceX * FarPlane), (float) (screenSpaceY * FarPlane), (float) (-FarPlane), 1);


    //Unproject the 2D window into 3D to see where in 3D we're actually clicking
    //Loading Matrices
    FloatBuffer modMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    FloatBuffer projMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modMatrix);
    glGetFloat(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projMatrix);

    // Assigning Matrices
    Matrix4f proj = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f model = new Matrix4f();
    model.load(modMatrix);
    proj.load(projMatrix);

    // Multiplying the Projection Matrix by the Model View Matrix
    Matrix4f tempView = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f.mul(proj, model, tempView);
    tempView.invert();

    Vector4f worldSpaceNear = new Vector4f();
    Matrix4f.transform(tempView, cameraSpaceNear, worldSpaceNear);

    Vector4f worldSpaceFar = new Vector4f();

    Matrix4f.transform(tempView, cameraSpaceFar, worldSpaceFar);

    //calculate the ray position and direction
    Vector3f rayPosition = new Vector3f(worldSpaceNear.x, worldSpaceNear.y, worldSpaceNear.z);
    Vector3f rayDirection = new Vector3f(worldSpaceFar.x - worldSpaceNear.x, worldSpaceFar.y - worldSpaceNear.y, worldSpaceFar.z - worldSpaceNear.z);

    rayDirection.normalise();

    Point p = new Point(rayPosition.x, rayPosition.y, rayPosition.z);

    return new Ray(p, rayDirection);
}
```

Here is my gluPerspective method call:

```
FIELD_OF_VIEW = 30;
gluPerspective(FIELD_OF_VIEW, 960f / 640f, 1f, 100f);
```

And my glLookAt method call.  The method references a custom Point Object that moves with the player.  The matrix is Pushed, LookedAt, and Popped every Render.  The values u, v, i, & j are determined and changed to be able to rotate the "camera" around the point.  The gluLookAt Call always comes before the attempt to make a ray.:

```
gluLookAt(
            //Camera Set Above the Reference Point
            (float) (lookAtPoint.getX() + u), (float)(lookAtPoint.getY() + v), (float) lookAtPoint.getZ() + zZoom,
            //The Reference Point
            (float) lookAtPoint.getX(), (float) lookAtPoint.getY(), (float) lookAtPoint.getZ(),
            //Setting the Up Vector
            i, j, 0f);
```

If I negate the vector, it's still off.  The X axis is counting what should be a movement of 1 as a movement of approx 0.03.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with the debugger? The answer I posted [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12360/how-do-you-determine-which-object-surface-the-users-pointing-at-with-lwjgl/12370#12370). Has a working example of projecting a ray.

Comment: I've stepped through it, and I just don't know what's going on.  I'm currently using your code almost verbatim, and I'm getting a ray pointed towards the camera, instead of away.  I'm editing the question again to show the updated changes, as well as my gluPerspective and glLookAt.

Comment: Why is @Byte56's version better than mine? :(

Comment: I tried yours too, I just can't seem to get either to work, and I don't know why. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I found your problem. I don't, however, know why it's the problem.

I plugged your code into mine, everything was the same except the matrices. The matrices retrieved from OpenGL did not match the ones I was generating. So, if you would, try upgrading your camera class to generate those matrices for you.

There's a few functions you'll need:

```
Matrix4f result = new Matrix4f();
...
Matrix4f CreateLookAt(Vector3f position, Vector3f direction, Vector3f up) {
    Vector3f.cross(up, direction, rightVector);
    rightVector = (Vector3f) rightVector.normalise();

    result.m00 = rightVector.x;
    result.m10 = rightVector.y;
    result.m20 = rightVector.z;
    result.m30 = -(Vector3f.dot(rightVector, position));

    result.m01 = up.x;
    result.m11 = up.y;
    result.m21 = up.z;
    result.m31 = -(Vector3f.dot(up, position));

    result.m02 = direction.x;
    result.m12 = direction.y;
    result.m22 = direction.z;
    result.m32 = -(Vector3f.dot(direction, position));

    return result;
}

private Matrix4f glhFrustumf2(Matrix4f matrix, float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float znear, float zfar) {
    float temp, temp2, temp3, temp4;
    temp = 2.0f * znear;
    temp2 = right - left;
    temp3 = top - bottom;
    temp4 = zfar - znear;
    matrix.m00 = temp / temp2;
    matrix.m01 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m02 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m03 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m10 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m11 = temp / temp3;
    matrix.m12 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m13 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m20 = (right + left) / temp2;
    matrix.m21 = (top + bottom) / temp3;
    matrix.m22 = (-zfar - znear) / temp4;
    matrix.m23 = -1.0f;
    matrix.m30 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m31 = 0.0f;
    matrix.m32 = (-temp * zfar) / temp4;
    matrix.m33 = 0.0f;
    return matrix;
}

Matrix4f CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(float fov, float aspect, float zn, float zf) {
    float ymax, xmax;
    ymax = (float) (zn * Math.tan(fov * Math.PI / 360.0));
    xmax = ymax * aspectRatio;
    Matrix4f result = new Matrix4f();
    glhFrustumf2(result, -xmax, xmax, -ymax, ymax, zn, zf);

    return result;
}
```

Then when updating your view and projection you'll use:

```
view = CreateLookAt(position, direction, upVector);
projection = CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(ViewAngle * zoomFactor, (float) WindowX / (float) WindowY, NearPlane, FarPlane);
```

Then there's the picking code:

```
public Ray GetPickRay(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
    float windowWidth = WindowX;
    float windowHeight = WindowY;

    double screenSpaceX = (mouseX / (windowWidth / 2) - 1.0f) * aspectRatio;
    double screenSpaceY = (1.0f - mouseY / (windowHeight / 2));
    double viewRatio = Math.tan(((float) Math.PI / (180.f/ViewAngle) / 2.00f)) * zoomFactor;

    screenSpaceX = screenSpaceX * viewRatio;
    screenSpaceY = screenSpaceY * viewRatio;

    cameraSpaceNear.set((float) (screenSpaceX * NearPlane), (float) (screenSpaceY * NearPlane),
            (-NearPlane), 1);
    cameraSpaceFar.set((float) (screenSpaceX * FarPlane), (float) (screenSpaceY * FarPlane),
            (-FarPlane), 1);

    tmpView.load(view);
    invView = (Matrix4f) tmpView.invert();
    Vector4f colonySpaceNear = new Vector4f();
    Matrix4f.transform(invView, cameraSpaceNear, colonySpaceNear);

    Vector4f colonySpaceFar = new Vector4f();

    Matrix4f.transform(invView, cameraSpaceFar, colonySpaceFar);

    rayPosition.set(colonySpaceNear.x, colonySpaceNear.y, colonySpaceNear.z);
    rayDirection.set(colonySpaceFar.x - colonySpaceNear.x,
            colonySpaceFar.y - colonySpaceNear.y, colonySpaceFar.z - colonySpaceNear.z);

    rayDirection.normalise();

    return new Ray(rayPosition, rayDirection);
}
```

Finally, when you're drawing your scene, you'll load in your camera matrices.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadMatrix(UtilFunctions.MatrixToFloatBuffer(COLONY.Camera.projection));
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadMatrix(UtilFunctions.MatrixToFloatBuffer(COLONY.Camera.view));
```

Phew! That should keep you busy for a bit and hopefully solve your problem!

Comment: I'm glad it's not just me misunderstanding the concept. I feel like I'm so close I can taste it.  The current formula is spot on accurate if the mouse is in the center of the screen. Unfortunately pointing at the same point in 3D space, but a different point on the window, the accuracy is off.

I notice that the above algorithm, or at least the way I implemented it, doesn't use the Projection Matrix.  When I tried to multiply the Modelview by the Projection, with a fixed Z to test to, my pointing to X & Y decided to go to Infinity.  Am I missing something?  You've already helped out so much.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it was a bug in my code. I was only supporting a camera view angle of `45` degrees. See the new line of code for `viewRatio`. Thanks for helping me find a bug!

Comment: I'm glad you found the bug, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue.  Right now, the coordinates are dead on for center screen, but the X value is off by around 3 at each side edge, and around 2 for the top and bottom edges.  I feel like it has something to do with the aspectRatio, since 3/2 == 960f/640f.

Comment: Strange, changing my aspect ratio works fine. You're calculating aspectRation like `(float) (windowX) / (float) (windowY);`? Is it kind of lagging behind the cursor or is it ahead of the cursor? Mine works with any aspect ratio and any view angle. Why don't you clean up your two edits and post your latest code.

Comment: Actually you were right.  I don't know how I kept overlooking it, but totally my fault.  Changing the ViewRatio makes it just run like a dream.  I owe you tons.

Comment: Excellent! Make a million dollars, give me one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not used to coding in Java, but I managed to fix it for you using code from Horde3D.

```
// Algorithm courtesy of Horde3D
// h3dutPickRay

public static Ray getPick(int mouseX, int mouseY)
{
    // Mouse position in NDC [-1, 1]

    Vector2f mouse_ndc = new Vector4f(
        (float)(mouseX / 960f) * 2f - 1f,  // TODO: Hardcoded viewport
        (float)(mouseY / 640f) * 2f - 1f,
    );

    // Get matrices

    FloatBuffer projMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    glGetFloat(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projMatrix);
    Matrix4f proj = new Matrix4f();
    proj.load(projMatrix);

    FloatBuffer modMatrix = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modMatrix);
    Matrix4f model = new Matrix4f();
    model.load(modMatrix);

    // Build inverse MVP

    Matrix4f inverse_mvp = new Matrix4f();
    Matrix4f.mul(proj, model, inverse_mvp);
    inverse_mvp.invert();

    // Ray starts at camera

    Vector3f ray_origin(
        -model.m30, 
        -model.m31, 
        -model.m32
    );

    // Get positions in NDC space

    Vector4f p0 = inverse_mvp * Vector4f(mouse_ndc.x, mouse_ndc.y, -1f, 1f);
    Vector4f p1 = inverse_mvp * Vector4f(mouse_ndc.x, mouse_ndc.y,  1f, 1f);

    // Normalize to 3D coordinates

    Vector3f p0_norm(
        p0.x / p0.w, 
        p0.y / p0.w, 
        p0.z / p0.w
    );

    Vector3f p1_norm(
        p1.x / p0.w, 
        p1.y / p0.w, 
        p1.z / p0.w
    );

    // Get ray direction

    Vector3f ray_direction = p1 - p0;
    // ray_direction.normalize(); // optional

    // Finish

    return new Ray(ray_origin, ray_direction);
}
```