# Inverse of perspective matrix, for what?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I dont understand for what i need the inverse of the perspective Matrix in Computer Graphics and how do i calculate it?Maybe someone has an explanation for me.

Comment: Could you add a bit more to the context? It's not clear what you need.

Comment: just about any matrix math library worth it salt will have an inverse operation.

Comment: If you don't need it, why do you want to calculate it?

Comment: @ratchetfreak right. but it's not the only thing there is to it. one needs not to forget the division by w stage, which is a bit tricky to invert, you need to choose an arbitrary w because it gets "lost in projection". and then multiply with the inverse matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inverse projection matrix can be used for mouse/ray picking (letting you click an object in the world)

For more info: [How do you determine which object/surface the user's pointing at with lwjgl?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12360/how-do-you-determine-which-object-surface-the-users-pointing-at-with-lwjgl/12370#12370)

Answer (score 3):

An inverse projection matrix is used to invert coordinates from the projected space to either world or local space, i.e. You can use the inverse projection matrix to find out where a pixel is in relation to game objects.

This can be extremly useful for postprocessing effects like deferred rendering.

Calculating it can be a bit tricky and requires knowledge in linear algebra, if you have an API handy I suggest using it. Or google around for a while.