# How to a select a single 3D object out of multiple objects using mouse click and move it using mouse drag in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, graphics

I am rendering multiple 3d objects on the screen but i want to select one particular object  by clicking on it and then move it using mouse drag but i cant figure it how to do it because on clicking on the screen all i get is the 2D coordinates of the mouse pointer

I am new to OpenGl Plsss help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you determine which object/surface the user's pointing at with lwjgl?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12360/how-do-you-determine-which-object-surface-the-users-pointing-at-with-lwjgl)

Comment: This is a problem called [tag:picking] and [there are lots of tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=opengl+picking) and past Q&A here showing ways to approach it. What have you tried based on your research so far, and where have you hit a problem that we can help you with?